# Dynamic jQuery hide div on mouseout

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I am trying to produce a tooltips style popup menu on a dynamic table generated using PHP. The table returns between 10 and 20 rows in a table. When I click on the item in the first table column, I want a popup submenu to appear in the style of a tooltip.

I've got the styling working to make it look how I want, but now I'm trying to get the functionality working!

I have managed to piece together the code to show and hide the div and it works well for one item. However, when I add more than one row in my test, it's very glitchy. I use the .click event, but with more than one item, you ended up having to double click. Can anyone help me get it to work better?

```js
 function myPopup(id) {
    $("#myPopup" + id).click(function() {
        if ($("#menudiv" + id).is(":hidden")) {
            //$("#menudiv"+id).fadeIn(500);
            $("#menudiv" + id).show();
        } else {
            $("#menudiv" + id).hide();
        }
    });
    $("#menudiv" + id).mouseleave(function() {
        $(this).hide();
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div style="padding-bottom:8px;">
                    <a href="#" id="myPopup1" onClick="javascript:myPopup(1);">Company Name</a>
                </div>
                <div id="menudiv1" style="position: fixed; display: none;">
                    <div class="tooltipMenu">
                        <span class="tooltiptext">View | Edit </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div style="padding-bottom:8px;">
                    <a href="#" id="myPopup2" onClick="javascript:myPopup(2);">Company Name</a>
                </div>
                <div id="menudiv2" style="position: fixed; display: none;">
                    <div class="tooltipMenu">
                        <span class="tooltiptext">View | Edit </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>

    </table>
```

Comment: that code will bind so many event handlers.

Answer (score 1):

Because you add function myPopup in event click of a tag, but You re-call click event in function myPopup. Please view my code:

```js
function myPopup(id){ 
  if ($("#menudiv"+id).is(":hidden")) {
   $("#menudiv"+id).fadeIn(500); 
   $("#menudiv"+id).show(); 
  } else { 
   $("#menudiv"+id).hide(); 
  } ; 
   
  $("#menudiv"+id).mouseleave(function(){ $(this).hide(); }); 
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr>
    <td>
    <div style="padding-bottom:8px;">
    <a href="#" id="myPopup1" onClick="javascript:myPopup(1);">Company Name</a>
    </div>
    <div id="menudiv1" style="position: fixed; display: none;">
        <div class="tooltipMenu">
            <span class="tooltiptext">View | Edit </span>
        </div>
    </div>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
    <div style="padding-bottom:8px;">
    <a href="#" id="myPopup2" onClick="javascript:myPopup(2);">Company Name</a>
    </div>
    <div id="menudiv2" style="position: fixed; display: none;">
        <div class="tooltipMenu">
            <span class="tooltiptext">View | Edit </span>
        </div>
    </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make it simpler if you know about jQuery Selector.

No need to define id for every single item. Here I change your original code.

```js
$('.trigger').click(function() {
 $(this).parent().next('.menu-wrap').show();
});

$('.menu-wrap').mouseleave(function() {
 $(this).hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr>
    <td>
    <div style="padding-bottom:8px;">
    <a href="#" class="trigger">Company Name</a>
    </div>
    <div class="menu-wrap" style="position: fixed; display: none;">
        <div class="tooltipMenu">
            <span class="tooltiptext">View | Edit </span>
        </div>
    </div>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
    <div style="padding-bottom:8px;">
    <a href="#" class="trigger">Company Name</a>
    </div>
    <div class="menu-wrap" style="position: fixed; display: none;">
        <div class="tooltipMenu">
            <span class="tooltiptext">View | Edit </span>
        </div>
    </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Hope this can help you.

Comment: Seems to work like a charm! Thanks! I'll go and try and put it into the PHP.

Comment: Saying that....as my dynamic table displays after scrolling down, the # tag on the link makes the page jump to the top...so I need to get round that now. :-)

Comment: Just remove it. If you just want make it as a trigger, you don't need to use "href" attribute.

Comment: Great - thanks. I've got that working on a test page. I'll see if I can get it working on my main page :-)

Answer (score 1):

Use `mouseover` and `mouseout` and bind these function. Use `mouseover` on the wrapping element like `td`, so the mouseover and mouseout event work properly

> The issue with the click is, if someone never enter in the tooltip then it will always show and will never get hidden until a mouseover event triggers on the tooltip.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".mypopup").mouseover(function() {
        $(this).find(".popupDiv").show();
    }).mouseout(function() {
        $(this).find(".popupDiv").hide();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
        <tr>
            <td class="mypopup">
                <div style="padding-bottom:8px;">
                    <a href="#" id="myPopup1" onClick="javascript:myPopup(1);">Company Name</a>
                </div>
                <div id="menudiv1" class="popupDiv" style="position: fixed; display: none;">
                    <div class="tooltipMenu">
                        <span class="tooltiptext">View | Edit 1 </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="mypopup">
                <div style="padding-bottom:8px;">
                    <a href="#" id="myPopup2" onClick="javascript:myPopup(2);">Company Name</a>
                </div>
                <div id="menudiv2" class="popupDiv" style="position: fixed; display: none;">
                    <div class="tooltipMenu">
                        <span class="tooltiptext">View | Edit 2 </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```